# Create PDF report with knit in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create PDF with knit without success. My HTML is good. I get the following error:

> output file: relJanFev_v2_pdf.knit.md ! Dimension too large.
>    \wd \@tempboxa  Error: Failed to compile
>   relJanFev_v2_pdf.tex. See relJanFev_v2_pdf.log for more info. In
>   addition: Warning message: running command '"pdflatex" -halt-on-error
>   -interaction=batchmode "relJanFev_v2_pdf.tex"' had status 1  Execution halted

I have a lot of plots, that I'm generating with ggiraph and ggplot2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to be sure, but ggiraph is for interactive graphs and you definitely cant have those in a pdf.  Did you ever get a build to work with one graph, before attaching a bunch?  pdf builds are temperamental and it is best to do it incrementally.

Comment: Thank you that is the problem the ggiraph. I take it out and works perfectly.